# How to invoke a fresh update of cookies on React App?

Tags: reactjs, react-cookie

I have a React app. I have the following react hook to get cookies using [react-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie).

```
const [cookies] = useCookies(["basket"]);
```

I already successfully get the cookie basket. Is there anyway for me to invoke a fresh update on the cookie "basket" if it was changed independently from this react app? I.e. a function for me to call to get the latest cookie value?

Comment: So you want to call a function as soon as there's a change in cookie value?

Comment: No, whenever I want to use the cookie throughout the code base, I want the latest update of that cookie. Common sense would tell me to just reuse `X = useCookies(["basket"]);` but they become invalid hook calls in the areas I want to use the updated cookie.

Comment: You can get the value of cookie using `cookies.basket` in your case. However I'm unsure about the issue you are facing with the invalid hook calls. If maybe you can give some reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

a quick fix, first remove the cookie first, then update it

1. cookies.remove('basket')
2. cookies.set('basket', updated_cookie)